# How to reset foreach autocomplete behavior in ReSharper

Tags: c#, visual-studio, foreach, autocomplete, resharper

How to reset the behavior back to original in ReSharper? I have no idea how it got broken (maybe a bug since the ReSharper update) but normally after typing `foreach` hitting the <kbd>TAB</kbd> and typing in `list` and hitting <kbd>TAB</kbd> again I would expect

```
foreach(var VARIABLE in list)
{

}
```

but instead this happens

```
foreach (var VARIABLE in list         {

}
```

This doesn't happen with ReSharper disabled. My current version is 2017.2 Ultimate.

If I could get away without resetting all the ReSharper settings that would have been nice.

Comment: Is that a typo, or is there no closing `)` on the foreach statement after completion?

Comment: It's not a typo. That's what the problem is - it removes the closing bracket `)` and inserts the opening `{` at the end of current line rather than on a new line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>It is [a known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-466171) for R# 2017.2 release.</strike>

Update: this issue has been fixed in [R# 2017.2.1 release](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/09/21/resharper-ultimate-2017-2-1/)