# VS2017 C# foreach snippet erases characters after pressing tab

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, code-snippets

I'm having this really frustrating problem with VS 2017, whenever I enter the snipper for "foreach", the following code appears

```
foreach (var VARIABLE in COLLECTION) {

}
```

with COLLECTION being the first selected. If I enter the name of a previously defined variable, it erases characters after the variable, e.g.

```
foreach (var VARIABLE in opt) {

}
```

I press tab to autocomplete "opt" to "options":

```
foreach (var VARIABLE in options
}
```

forcing me to rewrite the characters. It does not happen if I enter something without using auto-completion and it does not happen in the other snippets I've used so far ("if" and "for"). The code for the foreach snippet does not seem any different from the other two so I have no idea where this bug is coming from. Note that I have ReSharper installed.

Comment: Probly your pressed "insert" key?

Comment: I answered the same question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46096229/1802385

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset foreach autocomplete behavior in ReSharper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45998118/how-to-reset-foreach-autocomplete-behavior-in-resharper)